# LocalDateTime.toString - can the format be configured in the environment?

Tags: java, spring, date, formatting, environment

I have code that saves a LocalDateTime as a string using `myTime.toString`. It gets read back in using a Spring converter to convert from the String to a LocalDateTime. No formatting anywhere, it is set to use the system default.

In one environment reading it in because the default seems to be an incorrect format (`2019-03-01T11:51:07.017`)

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '2020-01-13T07:00'; nested exception is java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-01-13T07:00' could not be parsed at index 16
```

Is there any system-wide configuration of this property or should I just explicitly format everywhere?

Comment: You can store an instance of `DateTimeFormatter` somewhere and keep using that instead.

Comment: Did you specify an explicit format somewhere? The `LocalDateTime` class can parse both of those inputs without error (`2019-03-01T11:51:07.017` and `2020-01-13T07:00`).

Comment: No format anywhere. When I do a toString is there an environment property that says what the default is?

Comment: please check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString-- for default toString format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any system-wide configuration of this property …

No.

The format produced by `LocalDateTime.toString()` is fixed, you can’t alter it, not by any means. From the documentation:

> The output will be one of the following ISO-8601 formats:
>
> - `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm`
> - `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`
> - `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`
> - `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS`
> - `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS`
>
> The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of
>   the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.

So the only way you can influence the format is by controlling whether there are any seconds or fraction of second in you `LocalDateTime`.

> … or should I just explicitly format everywhere?

I am unsure whether that would help you. As Andreas said in the comment, the one-arg `LocalDateTime.parse()` parses both `2020-01-13T07:00` and `2019-03-01T11:51:07.017` just fine. The only explanation I can think of for your issue would be that some other formatter than the default one is used for parsing.

**Link**

- [Documentation of `LocalDateTime.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString())

Comment: Got it! I missed that in the spec, changed to use LocalDateTime.parse